# Allow certain email addresses to login via google in identity server

Tags: identityserver3, google-authentication

I would like to use identity server 3 with Google authentication to allow login from users with certain email addresses.

I can extract the email address from the claims in the `OnAuthenticated` method (`GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions.Provider.OnAuthenticated`).

I would then like to reject the login if the email address is not in a list of specific addresses.

I have tried implementing `IAuthenticationSessionValidator`, but I do not have an email claim there.

I have also tried `CookieAuthenticationOptions.Provider.OnValidateIdentity`, but no email claim there either.

How should I perform such an email authentication check with identity server 3 and Google provider?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I had to add scope 'email' in `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`.